# how can i achieve this using promises (Q package)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, q

I am developing an app with express.js and mongodb.
I want to do following task.
**If database is available then i want to fetch all posts else it will throw an error..** I am using **Q package** for promise. I am not sure how can i make the following code work.. If there is any other way to achieve this then help me out.

```
function getAllPosts(){

    var deferred = Q.defer();

    db.connectDB().then(function(){ 

    db.posts.find({},function(err,data){

        if(err){
            deferred.reject(new Error('problem'));
        }else{
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }
    });

    }).fail(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Here is my code for route **localhost:3000/posts**

```
exports.posts = function(req,res){
  postModel.getAllPosts().then(function(data){
    res.send(data);
  }).fail(function(err){
    res.send('error');
  });
}
```

**Here is my mongodb connection code**

```
function connectDB(){
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/demo');
        var deferred = q.defer();
    mongoose.connection.on('open',function(){
        createTables();
        deferred.resolve();
    });

    mongoose.connection.on('error',function(){

        deferred.reject(new Error('Error connecting database'));
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: *Of topic* : Is there a requirement to specially use `Q`. If not, just use node v0.12 with `--harmony` flag to use promises.

Comment: At the first sight it looks like the code is ok. What kind of error did you got?

Comment: @SimoEndre I am able to get error when  mongodb is not connected. But when i start mongodb and switch to the url localhost:3000/posts (which is suppose to return all the posts.),It's not returning data.. It is just keep loading...

Comment: Did you return a promise on `db.connectDB()` function?

Comment: @SimoEndre will you  please look at the edited code..?

Comment: In `getAllPosts()` in the `fail()` handler you need to reject the promise as well, instead of just logging something.

Comment: not working. have rejected promise as well

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `connection` method, because you are not instantiating the deferred object with capital letter `Q`.

You should use

```
var deferred = Q.defer();
```

instead of

```
var deferred = q.defer();
```

So your connection method should look like:

```
function connectDB(){
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/demo');
    var deferred = Q.defer(); // Q with capital letter
    mongoose.connection.on('open',function(){
        createTables();
        deferred.resolve();
    });

    mongoose.connection.on('error',function(){

        deferred.reject(new Error('Error connecting database'));
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: have tried it already.. I guess that is not causing the issue.

Comment: If you try without promise is it working? If you console the `data` do you get some data?